# ImportError: No module named comtypes in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-import, comtypes

I'm using Python 3.6. I have installed the module `comtypes` via  the command

```
python -m pip install comtypes
Requirement already satisfied: comtypes in c:\users\singtech\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
```

But I am still getting the import error for comtypes from my script:

```
import comtypes.client as cc
import comtypes

mylib = cc.GetModule("d:\\path\\to\\mylib.dll")
print(mylib)
```

When I run the script, it produces the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python-apps\aos.py", line 1, in <module>
    import comtypes.client as cc
ImportError: No module named 'comtypes'
```

Comment: How do you execute your script ?

Comment: I run the script in [Thonny IDE](http://thonny.org/)

Comment: You have installed your package in different interpreter that is used to run a script.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Oh I see. When I set up the correct interpreter path in Thonny IDE's option, I see the different error of loading DLL library. The original issue is solved.

Comment: Please add an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run the script in the Python beginner IDE [Thonny](http://thonny.org/). It uses a different interpreter. When I setup the correct interpreter path in IDE's options, the import error gone away.

[image]